# How do I update with a join and group by?

Tags: mysql

I want to do a query like this:

```
UPDATE State
LEFT JOIN Actions ON Actions.id = State.id
SET duration = FLOOR(AVG(duration)) WHERE type = 'started' GROUP BY Actions.id
```

How would I do this? (It says the group by is an error)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
UPDATE State
INNER JOIN 
(
   select id, FLOOR(AVG(duration)) as avg
   from Actions
   WHERE type = 'started'
   group by id        
) tmp ON tmp.id = State.id
SET duration = tmp.avg
```

Comment: This is almost the answer. Can you update the inner query to have `WHERE type - 'started'` and the outer query to be `WHERE State.id = tmp.id`? I'll mark it the answer with those changes

Comment: I changed it. The outer query does not need a `where` clause since the JOIN already filters the data in the `ON` clause when you use an `INNER JOIN` instead of a `LEFT JOIN`

Comment: The outer query does need it. When I ran without that, I get an error that it's trying to set a null value. But with that outer where, everything works correctly

Comment: Even when you change it into `INNER JOIN`?

Comment: Ah, didn't try that

Answer (score 0):

Short answer is:

UPDATE State LEFT JOIN Actions ON Actions.id = State.id
SET duration = FLOOR(AVG(duration)) WHERE Actions.id IN ( select id from Actions where Actions.id = state.id and type = 'started' GROUP BY Actions.id )

Probably not quite syntactically correct.

Comment: This isn't correct. It'll average all of them together.